# mysql search with multiple keywords touching

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql ="
        SELECT * FROM table

        WHERE $email_filter lower(table.synopsis) like '% $search_word_fix %'
        OR lower(table.sp_name) like '% $search_word_fix %'    
        GROUP by table.sp_name  
        ORDER BY table.grade DESC
        ";
    $re=mysql_query($sql);
```

so I have this simple sql query, if I search for 2 words for example: Hello World
it returns results for both the word: hello. and results for the word: world
I am trying to get it to return ONLY "hello word"
if I use: where table.field ='$keyword'
I get : no results. which I have phpmyadmin open and I know for a fact that there are results.
any help is appreciated it.thank you

Comment: Maybe DISTINCT sql statement helps you

Comment: I used distinct, it will return all results.for example if its a paragraph:" hello my name is blah, i live in this world. " would be a result. I only want it where the keywords are touching so must be something like "hello world!" or "hello world blabla"

Comment: is case sensitivity a problem? (does your instance of MySQL have case sensitivity turned on?) (and then since you are using lower, is the search_word_fix all LOWER?)... wait a second.. you're searching on $search_word_Fix.  not '%".$search_word_fix."%'  is the problem that the SQL is searching on your variable name instead of its value?

Comment: well it does return good results. if i search for names, titles, etc... the only issue is multikeyword.

Answer (score 0):

change the LIKE for =, the = force the word to be absolutly

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql ="
    SELECT * FROM table

    WHERE $email_filter lower(table.synopsis) REGEXP '[[:<:]]$search_word_fix[[:>:]]' = 1

    OR lower(table.sp_name) REGEXP '[[:<:]]$search_word_fix[[:>:]]' = 1
    GROUP by table.sp_name  
    ORDER BY table.grade DESC
    ";
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try removing that % sign. so the like query looks like

```
like '$search_word_fix'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE table.field LIKE '%Hello world%'
```

or

```
WHERE table.field LIKE '%Hello%world%'
```